# Matriz en forma de espiral

Tags: java

Trato de hacer una matriz en forma de espiral, pero al ejecutarlo en `cmd` me sale un error que no he podido corregir.

Adjunto el error y el código respectivamente.

> exception in thread main java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   -2147483648
>            at caracolfinal.main(caracolfinal.java:29)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class caracolfinal{
    public static void main(String args[]){


Scanner tcl=new Scanner(System.in);

int n=0;
int inicio=0;
int lim= n-1;
int cont=1;


System.out.println(" Ingrese el valor para N ");

n =tcl.nextInt();

    int [][] matriz = new int[n][n];

    while(cont<= (n*n))
    {
        for(int i=inicio;i<=lim;i++)
        {
            matriz[inicio][i]=cont++;

        }
        for(int i=inicio+1;i<=lim;i++)
        {
            matriz[i][lim]=cont++;
        }
        for(int i=lim-1;i>=inicio;i--)
        {
            matriz[lim][i]=cont++;
        }
        for(int i=lim-1;i>=inicio+1;i--)
        {

            matriz[i][inicio]=cont++;

        }
        inicio++;
        lim--;

    }
    for(int j=0;j<=matriz.length;j++){
        System.out.println();

        for(int i=0;i<=matriz.length;i++){
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+"\t");
    }

    }   

    }
}
```

Comment: Podrias definir que es una array caracol o espiral.

Comment: un arreglo en forma de espiral (o tambien llamado caracol).

Comment: Tu respuesta es ambigua, me has respondido parafraseando mi pregunta :P

Comment: Quiero ayudarte, pero no te entiendo, por eso te pido informacion, te recomiendo mejorar tu pregunta, y para ello debes leer lo siguiente: [ask], entiende que no estoy en tu cabeza, no sè a que te refieres, y muchos que queremos ayudarte estaran en mi misma situacion,

Comment: Ok. si entiendo que formule mal mi pregunto pero ok, tratare de expresarme mejor.   Necesito crear un arreglo en java. una matriz de dimension n(ingresado por el usuario), la cual me permita ir llenando con numeros en forma de espiral. Ejemplo una matriz de 5x5 : los numeros irian desde el 1-25 pero llenados en una matriz en forma de espiral. que el numero 1 quede en el centro de la matriz  (que en este caso seria en la posiciion ([2][2]) y el ultimo numero 25 quede en la posicion [0][0] de la matriz.      Espero que me entiendas y puedas ayudarme. Te agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Okay, ya te entendi, edita tu pregunta y añade esa descripcion

Comment: Ok. espero puedas ayudarme.

Comment: Creo que no me has entendido, adios. Descripcion es diferente a titulo.

Comment: SO tiene reglas, y si deseas que te ayudemos entonces debes cumplirla, y pienso que ni has leido el enlace que te pase, alli te dan consejos para hacer mas atractiva tu pregunta, tal como esta no me interesa resolverla, no somos un lugar que hace tareas.

Answer (score 1):

La variable `n` la inicializas en cero, `lim` es -1, ahora, el agravante es que `lim` queda con ese -1 y no con el valor registrado por teclado menos 1.

A lo que quiero ir es que actualices `lim` después de capturar por teclado la dimensión del array:

```
n = tcl.nextInt();
lim = n - 1;
```

Comment: Tu ayuda me fue muy útil. Te agradezco.

Comment: Perfecto, feliz navidad a ti y al Grinch downvoter. :D

Comment: pues ahí te va un +1 para compensar!